# Unable to save the session while making multiple requests using CURL

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I am trying to open a html page using CURL and then extracting the captcha image URL and saving the image as PNG. I am being able to do both but the image displayed on screen and the image file saved are different. How can I fix this?

```
//Get page contents first
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.gstsearch.in/track-provisional-id.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");


$pageContent = curl_exec ($ch);
$errNo = curl_errno($ch); //CURL error code
curl_close ($ch);


if($errNo == 0) {
    $imgURL = getCaptcha($pageContent); //Get captcha image
    saveCaptcha($imgURL); //Save the captcha image as PNG
}
else {
    $errorMsg = curl_strerror($errNo);
    echo "CURL error ({$errNo}):\n {$errorMsg}";
}




function getCaptcha($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $captchaImg = $dom->getElementById('captchacode');
    $imgSrc = $captchaImg->getAttribute('data-src');

    //URL of the current captcha image
    $imgURL = "https://www.gstsearch.in/{$imgSrc}";
    echo "<img src={$imgURL}>";

    return $imgURL;
}

function saveCaptcha($url) {
    $fp = fopen ("captcha.png", 'w+');

    $sc = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");

    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    curl_exec($sc);
    curl_close($sc);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**UPDATE:** I updated the code as per suggestions but still the same thing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not retaining any session information so your second cURL request will get an image that is unrelated to your first request. You should store and use the cookie you get back in the first request.

Comment: @jeoren, see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jeroen, remote site thinks that there are two different users: one posting the information, another is retrieving CAPTCHA :)

You can store (and re-use) `session_id` with this:

```
//this is to pass `session_id` between requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $some_path . 'cookie.txt');
//this is to store cookies for future requests, i.e. if you want to retain your session
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $some_path . 'cookie.txt');
```

you should use these for both requests. this way site will think that you are the same user, but not two different (as it thinks right now)